# How to view the datas of a neural network in matlab if they are "too many to view"?

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I trained a network, the first layer of which has 1392 weights, so i can not view them in nntool because they are "too many to view and edit".

[click me to see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtzXB.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can export the network from *nntool* to *Workspace* and then use:

```
wb = getwb(network);
```

or

```
[b,IW,LW] = separatewb(network,wb);
```

Comment: OK i got it. Thank you very much